# How to read resource file from unit test?

Tags: java, android, junit

I have a Java-only module in my Android project. In that project I want to have a unit test that reads the contents from a local json file that is stored in the resources folder. Android Studio changes the icon of the resources folder, so I'd think it recognises it as the resources folder.

How I'm reading:

```
String json = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.json"))
                .parallel()
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

folder structure:

```
+project
  +app (android)
  +module (java only)
    +src
      +main
        +java
          +package
            -the java file
        +resources
            -file.json
```

My question is how can I read the file?

**updated below**

```
URL resource1 = getClass().getResource("file.json");
URL resource2 = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.json");
URL resource3 = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("file.json");
URL resource4 = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("file.json");
```

All these are null. 
I've copied the json file to `resources/same.package.structure` too, but to no success.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Samuel I've added the answer. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug, should be fixed now:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63612779

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 7):

Don't need to do all this complicated stuff with ClassLoaders. You have access to test/resources directory from you /test/* classes.

[image]

[image]

**UPD**
This is how to deserialize file using its path using SimpleXML. So here source method param is your path to resource file

[image]

Comment: I have my resource files under /test/resources. How do you load the files?

Comment: @Rule just created/moved files to this directory.

Comment: I mean, with which Java statements do you load them

Comment: @Rule what to you mean by saying load. You have path to your file so if you want to access file object just use new File(PATH). Then you can deserialize it or do smh else

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for your answer. But I want to load the contents of a json in a String. Not an XML to a file.
And also: I work with a Java-only library module, not android library

Comment: @Rule dude it's not about son or xml. Your question is about how to read file from resources YOURCLASS yourclass = new Gson().fromJson(File(PATH), YOURCLASS.class); This is how to deserialize json file using GSON

Comment: @Rule change your question then. Because this answer is 100% correct

Comment: Dude I know, but the problem is that it cannot find the resource file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148724/discussion-between-rule-and-anton-kazakov).

Answer (score 3):

you should using `Paths.get(URI)` instead, for example:

```
ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

String json = Files.lines(Paths.get(loader.getResource("file.json").toURI()))
                   .parallel()
                   .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

this is because you run your tests in android platform, and the resoruces were **packaged** in a jar, please using `BufferedReader.lines` instead, for example:

```
ClassLoader  loader = activity.getClassLoader();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
   loader.getResourceAsStream("file.json"),"UTF-8"
));

String json = in.lines()
                .parallel()
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Hi, @Rule how about it now?

Comment: @Rule what about the json file location now ? is it in `main/resources/file.json`? you must obtain the `ClassLoader` from your `Activity` since that will be generated 2 apk separately.

Comment: It's a java-only module, so there's no Activity. I've put the json file in both `main/resources/` and `test/resources` but no luck

Comment: Hi, @Rule are you using android-test rather than unit-test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148721/discussion-between-rule-and-holi-java).

Comment: hm, this is java 11 and I m stuck at this old java8 project....